# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to implement GCM in my application. I've added `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'` to my app.gradle file and i'm getting the following errors:

```
Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(15) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(21) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(28) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(77, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(77, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(77, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(77, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
```

Here is my App.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

def AAVersion = '2.7'
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.47'
    compile 'javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.5'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.2'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
    compile 'com.squareup:tape:1.1.1'
    apt "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.14.4'
    apt "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.14.4"
    compile "com.splunk.mint:mint:4.3.0"
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
}
}
apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName "com.example"
    }
}
```

Here is my project.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'

    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation of Google Play Services causing this issue, but this is usually a case of not compiling with the correct api version.  Try setting both compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 22, since you're using 22.0.1 for build tools.

Comment: You have to check the dependencies of the com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0. You will find the support libraries v22.
They require API 22 to be compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Material Design" was introduced in API 21. You are compiling against API 19:

```
compileSdkVersion 19
```

and

```
targetSdkVersion 19
```

Try this:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
```

and

```
targetSdkVersion 21
```

(You technically do not have to compile against the same API as the target, but it is unwise to do so... it can cause some very strange and difficult to identify errors.)

Comment: Thanks, I changed the `play-services` from `8.1.0` to `7.5.0` and it worked. Also, rather than importing the entire `play-services`, I imported just what I needed instead (`play-services-maps:7.5.0` and `play-services-gcm:7.5.0`)